# Assign numbers to values of rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

lets say i have a dataframe

```
A     B     C
john  I     agree 
ryan  II    agree
rose  V     strongly agree 
Shawn VI    disagree
```

what i want to do is to assign numbers to C column values like this ?

```
A     B     C
john  I     1 
ryan  II    1
rose  V     2
Shawn VI    0
```

anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary`:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].map({'agree':1, 'strongly agree':2, 'disagree':0})
print (df)
       A   B  C
0   john   I  1
1   ryan  II  1
2   rose   V  2
3  Shawn  VI  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` as well

```
        A               C
0  john           agree
1  ryan  strongly agree
2  rose        disagree
```

Just do

```
df_t['C'] = df_t['C'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x =='agree' else (0 if x=='disagree' else 2))
```

which results with

```
     A  C
0  john  1
1  ryan  2
2  rose  0
```

But using `map` as is pointed above by @jezrael is the best solution.